# How does howtogeek.com fit into the league of justice?

Tags: discussion, site-crossover, howtogeek

From howtogeek's friends:

```
 stackoverflow.com [programming]    
 serverfault.com [sysadmin]    
 doctype.com [web design]
 superuser.com [computing]
```

Sorry if I'm missing something, but where exactly does howtogeek fit into all of this? What type of questions should we ask at http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/ ?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/how-to-geek-at-superuser-new-moderator-footer-link

Answer (score 2):

How-To-Geek and DocType are members of the [League of Justice](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/howtogeek-and-stack-overflow/), but are not exactly part of the Stack Exchange network. That said, according to their [FAQ](http://www.howtogeek.com/about/), How-To-Geek provides how-to guides to technology, and questions should be emailed to them, as they are not a Q&A site, as I understand.

Comment: OK, so they're not primarily a Q&A site, but what type of questions should be asked in their forum? http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/

Comment: @Crazy If you look at the right hand bar of that page, you see the list of various forums that are available to choose from, and their names generally give a very good indication to what types of questions should be posted in each forum.